# Getting CORS error while using LinkedIn developer API

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm using developer API to get access from user, I have set localhost and required domains in settings widget portal and added redirect URI in auth but still it's giving CORS error, These API's can be used in front-end or can be used from back-end.

I tried by setting CORS extension in chrome it's not working but same is working in postman, is there any way to remove CORS error in development?

Comment: For chrome there are some addons like [cors-unblock](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino) and [allow-cors-access-control](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) that may help.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn developer API's can't be used from-end, if we want to use it we have to use along with back-end API's, or else we will get CORS error, although if we add any cors blocking extensions.